# How to take backup and restore data from vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am developing a desktop application in vb.net for student details management.

In that I want to add feature of backup and restore the data. By using this feature user should be able to take data backup and when he wants he should be able to restore data again (if system crash occurs) so data will not be lost.

How to do that using vb.net code, I am using VS2008.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [how to put bakeup and restore facility in vb.net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880395/how-to-put-bakeup-and-restore-facility-in-vb-net-application) Please fix your original question instead of opening it again.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is too open ended to get good responses. Please consider adding source code or an example. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read [ask] ... "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute BACKUP & RESTORE commands just the same way as any other via vb.net, so something like this would do it...

```
Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=master;User ID=sa;Trusted_Connection=true")

sqlConn.Open()

Dim sCommand = "BACKUP DATABASE [YourDatabaseName] TO DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Backup.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY"

Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sCommand, sqlConn)
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Where obviously your database name would replace [YourDatabaseName]. The equivalent RESTORE command would be something like this...

```
sCommand = "RESTORE DATABASE [YourDatabaseName] FROM DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\TestBackup.bak' WITH REPLACE"

Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sCommand, sqlConn)
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

You would need to review the documentation for these commands to tailor them to your specific scenario.

Comment: Database name is Database1.mdf so should i write database1 or database1.mdf???? Or whole path with c:\programfiles???? Thank you   And Here In your Answer What is N? ? at Disk=....

Comment: N states that the following string is a Unicode string, it's good practice to use it. Use `[database1]`. Please read the documentation on Backup & Restore because while this will work it is for guidance only.

Comment: `"BACKUP DATABASE Database1 TO DISK = N' C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\Backup.bak ' with COPY_ONLY"     `

Comment: I did this but its giving me error like "Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database 'DetailDatabase'. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly. BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally."

Comment: Check your database name in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Can you issue the backup command in SSMS? Does the user id you are using to access the db have the right privileges? Does the backup location exist? Do you have write access to it? The calls I gave you are *examples only*.